# xCode 3.2.6. Audio unit programming. IIR filter

Tags: xcode, audio, filter

My name's Antonio from Italy.
I'm trying to create an Audio Unit using xCode 3.2.6, starting from the example at
[this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH5-SW4).
 
This is my first AU project, and I have no other examples to follow.
My project consists of an IIR notch filter. The algorithm I made works fine (I tested in on Matlab), but the AU doesn't work properly (tested on AU Lab). The .mp3 file sounds filtered, but something like a square wave (I suppose by ear) is overlapped with it.
The frequency of that noise seems to be proportional to the f0 parameter.
Here is the .cpp file code:

```
// Filtro.cpp

#include "Filtro.h"
#define pi  3.1415926535



//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

COMPONENT_ENTRY(Filtro)


//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Filtro::Filtro
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Filtro::Filtro (AudioUnit component) : AUEffectBase (component) {
    CreateElements ();  
    Globals () -> UseIndexedParameters (kNumberOfParameters);
    SetParameter (kParameter_Gain, kDefaultValue_Gain);
    SetParameter (kParameter_f0, kDefaultValue_f0);
    SetParameter (kParameter_Q, kDefaultValue_Q);

//    code for setting default values for the audio unit parameters

}



//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Filtro::GetParameterInfo
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#pragma mark ____Parameters

ComponentResult Filtro::GetParameterInfo (
                                               AudioUnitScope          inScope,
                                               AudioUnitParameterID    inParameterID,
                                               AudioUnitParameterInfo  &outParameterInfo       
                                               ) {
    ComponentResult result = noErr;
    outParameterInfo.flags =    kAudioUnitParameterFlag_IsWritable        
    | kAudioUnitParameterFlag_IsReadable;
    if (inScope == kAudioUnitScope_Global) {                             
        switch (inParameterID) {
            case kParameter_Gain:                                      
                AUBase::FillInParameterName (
                                         outParameterInfo,
                                         kParamName_Gain,
                                         false
                                         );
            outParameterInfo.unit = kAudioUnitParameterUnit_Decibels;
            outParameterInfo.minValue = kMinimumValue_Gain;
            outParameterInfo.maxValue = kMaximumValue_Gain;
            outParameterInfo.defaultValue = kDefaultValue_Gain;
            break;
        case kParameter_f0:                                        // 9
            AUBase::FillInParameterName (
                                         outParameterInfo,
                                         kParamName_f0,
                                         false
                                         );
            outParameterInfo.unit = kAudioUnitParameterUnit_Hertz;
            outParameterInfo.minValue = kMinimumValue_f0;
            outParameterInfo.maxValue = kMaximumValue_f0;
            outParameterInfo.defaultValue = kDefaultValue_f0;
            outParameterInfo.flags |= kAudioUnitParameterFlag_DisplayLogarithmic;
            break;
        case kParameter_Q:                                        // 9
            AUBase::FillInParameterName (
                                         outParameterInfo,
                                         kParamName_Q,
                                         false
                                         );
            outParameterInfo.unit = kAudioUnitParameterUnit_Generic;
            outParameterInfo.minValue = kMinimumValue_Q;
            outParameterInfo.maxValue = kMaximumValue_Q;
            outParameterInfo.defaultValue = kDefaultValue_Q;
            outParameterInfo.flags |= kAudioUnitParameterFlag_DisplayLogarithmic;
            break;

        default:
            result = kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter;
            break;

    }

} else {

    result = kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter;

}

return result;

}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Filtro::GetPropertyInfo
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
OSStatus            Filtro::GetPropertyInfo (           AudioUnitPropertyID inID,
                                                AudioUnitScope      inScope,
                                                AudioUnitElement    inElement,
                                                UInt32              &outDataSize,
                                                Boolean             &outWritable)
{
        return AUEffectBase::GetPropertyInfo (inID, inScope, inElement, outDataSize, outWritable);
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Filtro::GetProperty
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
OSStatus            Filtro::GetProperty(        AudioUnitPropertyID inID,
                                            AudioUnitScope      inScope,
                                            AudioUnitElement    inElement,
                                            void                *outData )
    {
    return AUEffectBase::GetProperty (inID, inScope, inElement, outData);
}


    #pragma mark ____FiltroEffectKernel

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

//    Filtro::FiltroKernel::FiltroKernel()

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Filtro::FiltroKernel::FiltroKernel (AUEffectBase *inAudioUnit) :

AUKernelBase (inAudioUnit), mSamplesProcessed (0), mCurrentScale (0) // 1
{

    mSampleFrequency = GetSampleRate ();

}




//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Filtro::FiltroKernel::Reset()
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void Filtro::FiltroKernel::Reset() {
    mCurrentScale        = 0;           
    mSamplesProcessed    = 0;           
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Filtro::FiltroKernel::Process 
void Filtro::FiltroKernel::Process (const Float32   *inSourceP,                                      
                                          Float32         *inDestP,                                         
                                          UInt32          inSamplesToProcess,                             
                                          UInt32          inNumChannels,                                    
                                          bool            &ioSilence                                        
                                          ) {
if (!ioSilence) {                                                       
    const Float32 *sourceP = inSourceP;
    Float32  *destP = inDestP, inputSample, outputSample;
    Float32 Fs= mSampleFrequency;
    int f0;
    float   w0, alpha, b0, b1, b2, a0, a1, a2;
    float gain, dBgain, Q, coeff[5], x[5]={0,0,0,0,0} , out = 0;    

    dBgain = GetParameter (kParameter_Gain);                        //Get parameter from interface
    if (dBgain < kMinimumValue_Gain) dBgain = kMinimumValue_Gain;   //Check the right range
    if (dBgain > kMaximumValue_Gain) dBgain = kMaximumValue_Gain;
    f0 = GetParameter (kParameter_f0);          
    if (f0 < kMinimumValue_f0) f0 = kMinimumValue_f0;
    if (f0 > kMaximumValue_f0) f0 = kMaximumValue_f0;
    Q = GetParameter (kParameter_Q);            
    if (Q < kMinimumValue_Q) Q = kMinimumValue_Q;
    if (Q > kMaximumValue_Q) Q = kMaximumValue_Q;


    w0      = 2*pi*f0/Fs;
    alpha   = sin(w0)*sinh(log(2)/(log(exp(1))*2) * Q * w0/sin(w0));
    b0      = 1;
    b1      = -2*cos(w0);
    b2      = 1;
    a0      = 1 + alpha;
    a1      = -2*cos(w0);
    a2      = 1 - alpha;
    coeff[0] = b0/a0;
    coeff[1] = b1/a0;
    coeff[2] = b2/a0;
    coeff[3] = -a1/a0;
    coeff[4] = -a2/a0;      


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //  y(n) = b0/a0 * x(n) + b1/a0 * x(n-1) + b2/a0 * x(n-2) * -a1/a0 * y(n-1) * -a2/a0 * y(n-2)   //
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    for (int i = inSamplesToProcess; i > 0; --i) {
       int index = static_cast<long>(mSamplesProcessed * mCurrentScale) % 512;  //?

        if ((mNextScale != mCurrentScale) && (index == 0)) {      //?? 
            mCurrentScale = mNextScale;
            mSamplesProcessed = 0;

        }

        if ((mSamplesProcessed >= sampleLimit) && (index == 0)) {  // ??
            mSamplesProcessed = 0;

        }   

        gain            = pow(10, dBgain/20);
        inputSample     = *sourceP;
        x[0]            = inputSample;      //x(n)
        x[3]            = outputSample;     //y(n-1)    
        for (int h = 0; h < 5; h++) {       // Processing output sample
           out = out+x[h]*coeff[h];     
        }
        for (int h = 4; h > 0; h--) {
            x[h]=x[h-1];                    //I/O array shifting
        }
        outputSample        = out * gain;
        out                 = 0;
        *destP              = outputSample;
        sourceP             += 1;
        destP               += 1;
        mSamplesProcessed   += 1;
    }
}
}
```

And that's the header file:

```
// Filtro.h

#include "AUEffectBase.h"

#include "AUEffectBase.h"
#include "FiltroVersion.h"

#if AU_DEBUG_DISPATCHER
    #include "AUDebugDispatcher.h"
#endif


#ifndef __Filtro_h__
#define __Filtro_h__


#pragma mark ____Filtro Parameter Constants


static CFStringRef kParamName_Gain      = CFSTR ("Gain");  
static const double kDefaultValue_Gain   = 0;
static const double kMinimumValue_Gain   = -40;
static const double kMaximumValue_Gain   = 0;

static CFStringRef kParamName_f0      = CFSTR ("f0");  
static const int kDefaultValue_f0   = 1048;
static const int kMinimumValue_f0   = 50;
static const int kMaximumValue_f0   = 20000;

static CFStringRef kParamName_Q      = CFSTR ("Q");  
static const double kDefaultValue_Q   = 0.1;
static const double kMinimumValue_Q   = 0.001;
static const double kMaximumValue_Q   = 10;



// parameter identifiers
enum {                                                                    // Defines     constants for identifying the parameters; defines the total number of parameters
kParameter_Gain         = 0,
kParameter_f0           = 1,
kParameter_Q            = 2,
kNumberOfParameters     = 3
};


#pragma mark ____Filtro
class Filtro : public AUEffectBase
{
public:
    Filtro(AudioUnit component);
#if AU_DEBUG_DISPATCHER
    virtual ~Filtro () { delete mDebugDispatcher; }
#endif

    virtual AUKernelBase *      NewKernel() { return new FiltroKernel(this); }

    virtual OSStatus            GetParameterInfo(AudioUnitScope         inScope,
                                             AudioUnitParameterID   inParameterID,
                                             AudioUnitParameterInfo &outParameterInfo);

virtual OSStatus            GetPropertyInfo(AudioUnitPropertyID     inID,
                                            AudioUnitScope          inScope,
                                            AudioUnitElement        inElement,
                                            UInt32 &            outDataSize,
                                            Boolean &           outWritable );

virtual OSStatus            GetProperty(AudioUnitPropertyID     inID,
                                        AudioUnitScope          inScope,
                                        AudioUnitElement        inElement,
                                        void *                  outData);

virtual bool                SupportsTail () { return false; }   // FIND

/*! @method Version */
virtual OSStatus        Version() { return kFiltroVersion; }

//      virtual ComponentResult GetPresets (CFArrayRef *outData) const;
//      virtual OSStatus NewFactoryPresetSet (const AUPreset &inNewFactoryPreset);   

protected:
    class FiltroKernel : public AUKernelBase {

    public:
        FiltroKernel (AUEffectBase *inAudioUnit); // 1
        virtual void Process (
                          const Float32    *inSourceP,
                          Float32          *inDestP,
                          UInt32           inFramesToProcess,
                          UInt32           inNumChannels,       // equal to 1
                          bool             &ioSilence
                          );
    virtual void Reset();

private:
    Float32  mSampleFrequency;                    
    long     mSamplesProcessed;                 
    enum     {sampleLimit = (int) 10E6};         
    float    mCurrentScale;                       
    float    mNextScale;                          
    };
};
#endif#include "FiltroVersion.h"

#if AU_DEBUG_DISPATCHER
    #include "AUDebugDispatcher.h"
#endif


#ifndef __Filtro_h__
#define __Filtro_h__


#pragma mark ____Filtro Parameter Constants



static CFStringRef kParamName_Gain      = CFSTR ("Gain");  
static const double kDefaultValue_Gain   = 0;
static const double kMinimumValue_Gain   = -40;
static const double kMaximumValue_Gain   = 0;

static CFStringRef kParamName_f0      = CFSTR ("f0");  
static const int kDefaultValue_f0   = 1048;
static const int kMinimumValue_f0   = 50;
static const int kMaximumValue_f0   = 20000;

static CFStringRef kParamName_Q      = CFSTR ("Q");  
static const double kDefaultValue_Q   = 0.1;
static const double kMinimumValue_Q   = 0.001;
static const double kMaximumValue_Q   = 10;



// parameter identifiers
enum {                                                                    // Defines     constants for identifying the parameters; defines the total number of parameters
kParameter_Gain         = 0,
kParameter_f0           = 1,
kParameter_Q            = 2,
kNumberOfParameters     = 3
};


#pragma mark ____Filtro
class Filtro : public AUEffectBase
{
public:
    Filtro(AudioUnit component);
#if AU_DEBUG_DISPATCHER
    virtual ~Filtro () { delete mDebugDispatcher; }
#endif

    virtual AUKernelBase *      NewKernel() { return new FiltroKernel(this); }

    virtual OSStatus                GetParameterInfo(AudioUnitScope         inScope,
                                             AudioUnitParameterID   inParameterID,
                                             AudioUnitParameterInfo &outParameterInfo);

virtual OSStatus                GetPropertyInfo(AudioUnitPropertyID     inID,
                                            AudioUnitScope          inScope,
                                            AudioUnitElement        inElement,
                                            UInt32 &            outDataSize,
                                            Boolean &           outWritable );

virtual OSStatus            GetProperty(AudioUnitPropertyID     inID,
                                        AudioUnitScope          inScope,
                                        AudioUnitElement        inElement,
                                        void *                  outData);

virtual bool                SupportsTail () { return false; }

/*! @method Version */
    virtual OSStatus        Version() { return kFiltroVersion; }



protected:
    class FiltroKernel : public AUKernelBase {

    public:
        FiltroKernel (AUEffectBase *inAudioUnit); 
    virtual void Process (
                          const Float32    *inSourceP,
                          Float32          *inDestP,
                          UInt32               inFramesToProcess,
                          UInt32           inNumChannels,   // equal to 1
                          bool             &ioSilence
                          );
    virtual void Reset();

    private:
        Float32  mSampleFrequency;                    
        long     mSamplesProcessed;                   
        enum     {sampleLimit = (int) 10E6};          
    float    mCurrentScale;                      
    float    mNextScale;                          
    };
};
#endif
```

Thank a lot. I hope my English is not too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!! After 3 days, I found the right way to avoid the variables reset every audio frame. I just declared those state variables into the Filtro.h file at the fourth line from the bottom, and than I initialised them into the "AUKernelBase (inAudioUnit)" in Filtro.cpp file. I hope it can be helpful to other people. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter implementation does not look correct to me. Maybe it's fine, but it's hard to follow. For example, it looks like you are shifting your stored x values into your stored y values, and even though you clear that up on the next loop, it's all a bit hard to follow.

You might want to check out how I do it here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html Much cleaner!

Also, are you processing mono samples or multichannel audio, because your Process function looks like it will only work as you intend with mono audio. (I haven't worked with AU's recently enough to be able to answer this myself from looking at your code)

Comment: You're right about the x[] array. I'm sorry. Today I found a lot of superfluous code, but I'm sure that it works fine... I suppose that the problem is: everytime the "for (int i = inSamplesToProcess; i > 0; --i)" cycle ends, some variables (maybe x[]) take a wrong value. The variable inSampleToProcess is equal to "input frames". In fact, if I test the AU on AU Lab and I set an higher number of frames, the niose become very very soft, and the filter works better. I tried it on mono and stereo files, and it works in the same way. Let me look at your link. Thanks again

Comment: I modified my code following your example. Now it's clean like yours but it doesn't work. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: Problem solved!!! After 3 days, I found the right way to avoid the variables reset every audio frame. I just declared those state variables into the Filtro.h file at the fourth line from the bottom, and than I initialised them into the "AUKernelBase (inAudioUnit)" in Filtro.cpp file. I hope it can be helpful to other people. Bye.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.